# Not using fixtures for specific unit tests under Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a few tests in my suite that absolutely need an empty database to run.

Thing is, rails is automatically loading the fixtures for every test, and I can't seem to find a way to have it not load for this specific test.

I could drop the database before each test, but that's slow and requires all other tests that require fixtures to reload the fixtures afterwards.

Is there any way to have a certain test class (i.e. "NoFixturesTest") not load the fixtures (or unload them), without breaking all other tests?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Thanks to the answer below, I made this:

```
module DisableFixturesHelper
    def self.included(base)
        base.setup :setup_drop_db

        # Have a unit test double-check that the fixtures are really gone
        base.test "0 fixtures not loaded" do
            assert_equal 0, Table1.count, "Table1 isn't empty!"
            #etc
        end
    end

    # Call to reset the db and therefore disable fixtures during a single unit test
    def setup_drop_db
        Rails.logger.info { "Dropping database." }
        DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    end
end
```

And then in the TestCases that require an empty database (no fixtures), I add

```
include DisableFixturesHelper
```

The problem with this is that this drops the database once per test, AFTER the fixtures have already been loaded, so it's really slow. It's literally reloading the fixtures before the start of each unit test, just to drop them.

Still, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you know [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) ???

maybe it can help, you can also define what don't delete

something like:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[widgets]}
```

here is an initializer that I always use:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought this reset the DB back to the fixtures? Or am I wrong? The documentation never mentions otherwise.

Comment: Just tested and it works, but it's still loading the fixtures, only to drop them before the tests run... Is there really no other way?

Comment: to be honest, I never use Fixtures, I use Factories, and they are not loaded by default, not sure how fixtures work, btw I just updated my answer with a n initializer that I always use with DatabaseCleaner